# RecyclerView doesn't load data in first launch using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to populate a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`.

Here's my code

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
myAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(Product.class,
        R.layout.product_item,ProductViewHolder.class,
        mDatabase.child("clothes")) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.name.setText(model.name);
        viewHolder.price.setText(model.price);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.imageUri).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
        Log.d("NAME", model.name);
    }
};

recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

The problem is, the `ProgressBar` keeps moving in the first launch, it never hides and the `RecyclerView` never shows itself but If I exit the app and launch again, the `RecyclerView` is properly populated, even if the screen locks itself and I unlock it, the `RecyclerView` is populated. I'm confused.

Comment: Is the code segment from `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)` from your code and then check if the code works fine now.

And for dismissing the `ProgressBar`, its good to set the visibility to `GONE`.

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

For more information you can see this [Github link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/204). I think the same issue is reported here.

Comment: Thanks! 
It was driving me crazy! :)

Comment: Glad to know  that helped!

Answer (score 0):

In your activity.xml file, set ProgressBar property

`android:visibility="invisible"`

and in your populateViewHolder method, set  `mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
after setting data to TextViews & ImageView

```
 protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(model.name);
        viewHolder.price.setText(model.price);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.imageUri).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("NAME", model.name);
    }
```